# AlternateTemplate is not working for Listview

Tags: asp.net, listview, asp.net-3.5

I modified Listview as per my need,but now  is not working, in means, its showing row with different color but repeating same data. And then coming next data, againg its repeating and going on.... Here I am lisitng my code.

for Example,

```
1
1 (Repeating, Different Color row)
2
2 (Repeating, Different Color row)
3
3 (Repeating, Different Color row)
.
.
.
.
```

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="uniqueno">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color:#DCDCDC;color: #000000;" runat="server">

            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="policeNumLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("policeNum") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="DFirstNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", Eval("DFirstName"),Eval("DMidName"),Eval("DSurName")) %>' />
            </td>

            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="DLicenceNoLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("DLicenceNo") %>' />
            </td>

            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="ManufacturerLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Manufacturer") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="SerialNumLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SerialNum") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="ModelLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Model") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CalibreLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Calibre") %>' />
            </td>


            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="TypeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Type") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="ActionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Action") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="BarrelLengthLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("BarrelLength") %>' />
            </td>

            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="ReasonLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Reason") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="OtherLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Other") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="TransferPendingLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TransferPending") %>' />
            </td>

            <td>
               <asp:Label ID="OFirstNameLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", Eval("OFirstName"),Eval("OmidName"),Eval("OSurName")) %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="O_LicenceNoLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("O_LicenceNo") %>' />
            </td> 
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="DateAcqLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DateAcq") %>' />
            </td>

            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Dis_FirstnameLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# String.Format("{0} {1} {2}",Eval("Dis_Firstname"),Eval("Dis_Midname"),Eval("Dis_Surname")) %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Dis_LicenceNoLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Dis_LicenceNo") %>' />
            </td> 
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Dis_DisposaldateLabe" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Dis_Disposaldate") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Dis_CommentLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Dis_Comment") %>' />
            </td>

            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="PermittoAcqNoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PermittoAcqNo") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>

    </ItemTemplate>

   <AlternatingItemTemplate>
   <tr id="Tr1" style="background-color:#DCDCDC;color: #000000;" runat="server">

            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="policeNumLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("policeNum") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="DFirstNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", Eval("DFirstName"),Eval("DMidName"),Eval("DSurName")) %>' />
            </td>

            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="DLicenceNoLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("DLicenceNo") %>' />
            </td>

            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="ManufacturerLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Manufacturer") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="SerialNumLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SerialNum") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="ModelLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Model") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CalibreLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Calibre") %>' />
            </td>


            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="TypeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Type") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="ActionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Action") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="BarrelLengthLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("BarrelLength") %>' />
            </td>

            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="ReasonLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Reason") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="OtherLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Other") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="TransferPendingLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TransferPending") %>' />
            </td>

            <td>
               <asp:Label ID="OFirstNameLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", Eval("OFirstName"),Eval("OmidName"),Eval("OSurName")) %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="O_LicenceNoLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("O_LicenceNo") %>' />
            </td> 
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="DateAcqLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DateAcq") %>' />
            </td>

            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Dis_FirstnameLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# String.Format("{0} {1} {2}",Eval("Dis_Firstname"),Eval("Dis_Midname"),Eval("Dis_Surname")) %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Dis_LicenceNoLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Dis_LicenceNo") %>' />
            </td> 
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Dis_DisposaldateLabe" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Dis_Disposaldate") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Dis_CommentLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Dis_Comment") %>' />
            </td>

            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="PermittoAcqNoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PermittoAcqNo") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
   </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <table runat="server" 
            style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    No data found</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>



    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table runat="server">
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server">
                    <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="1" 
                        style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                        <tr runat="server" >
                            <th colspan="3" runat="server">Dealer Info </th>
                            <th colspan="7" runat="server">Firearm Details </th>
                            <th colspan="3" runat="server">Reason </th>
                            <th colspan="3" runat="server">Acquisition Details </th>
                            <th colspan="5" runat="server">Disposal Details </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr runat="server" style="background-color:#DCDCDC;color: #000000;">
                            <th runat="server">Number</th>
                            <th runat="server">Name</th>
                            <th runat="server">Licence #</th>

                            <th runat="server">Manufacturer</th>
                            <th runat="server">Serial #</th>
                            <th runat="server">Model</th>
                            <th runat="server">Calibre</th>
                            <th runat="server">Type</th>
                            <th runat="server">Action</th>
                            <th runat="server">Barrel Length</th>

                            <th runat="server">Reason</th>
                            <th runat="server">Other</th>
                            <th runat="server">Transfer Pending</th>

                            <th runat="server">Name</th>
                            <th runat="server">Licence #</th>
                            <th runat="server">Date of Acquired</th>


                            <th runat="server">Name</th>
                            <th runat="server">Licence #</th>
                            <th runat="server">Date of Disposal</th>
                            <th runat="server">Comment</th>
                            <th runat="server">Permit to Acquire No</th>

                        </tr>
                        <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server" 
                    style="text-align: center;background-color: #CCCCCC;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #000000;">
                    <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server">
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" 
                                ShowLastPageButton="True" />
                        </Fields>
                    </asp:DataPager>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>



    <SelectedItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color:#008A8C;font-weight: bold;color: #FFFFFF;">
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="policeNumLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("policeNum") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="DFirstNameLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("DFirstName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="DMidNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DMidName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="DSurNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DSurName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="DLicenceNoLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("DLicenceNo") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Dis_DisposaldateLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Dis_Disposaldate") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="SerialNumLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SerialNum") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CalibreLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Calibre") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="BarrelLengthLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("BarrelLength") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="ManufacturerLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Manufacturer") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="OtherLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Other") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="ModelLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Model") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="TypeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Type") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="ActionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Action") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="TransferPendingLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("TransferPending") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="DateAcqLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DateAcq") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="OFirstNameLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("OFirstName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="OmidNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OmidName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="OSurNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OSurName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="O_LicenceNoLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("O_LicenceNo") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="DNoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DNo") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="StreetLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Street") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="column1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("column1") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="StateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("State") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="PostCodeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PostCode") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="PermittoAcqNoLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("PermittoAcqNo") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Dis_FirstnameLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Dis_Firstname") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Dis_MidnameLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Dis_Midname") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Dis_SurnameLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Dis_Surname") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Dis_LicenceNoLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Dis_LicenceNo") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Dis_DnoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Dis_Dno") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Dis_StreetLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Dis_Street") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="column2Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("column2") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Dis_stateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Dis_state") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Dis_postcodeLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Dis_postcode") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Dis_CommentLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Dis_Comment") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="ReasonLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Reason") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </SelectedItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was no fault with code....
After having lots of experiment, I realise that there something wrong with my Database, and that's what happened, there was duplicate existed which were removed and now listview is work fine.